# Why can't I break blocks in Minecraft: Education edition?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I've been playing Minecraft (Education edition) for a while and I'm not able to break blocks. I'm in creative mode and I am not holding a sword. I've left clicked so many times!

Answer (score 3):

If this is a world that you are an operator on then just use the command `/wb` for yourself. If you want to unlock the world for everyone, use `/immutableworld false`. If there are deny blocks involved then the `/immutableworld` command won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you used it at school, your teacher probably placed [deny blocks](https://minecrafteducation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001433327-Specialty-Blocks-Allow-Deny-Border-Structure-) or you didn't had worldbuilder permission